# How can i create an org chart and display it in outlook

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

Recently was trying to create an Org chart to reflect our organisation. However when I open users account in outlook it shows the following:

[image: No org chart]

I have been doing a research on this and found out that I can use Visio however when an org chart is done for a user, how can I import it into Outlook?

Would be nice to see something like this:

[image: Org chart]